# Submit gcloud ai-platform training job programmatically (from python code)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-ml

To submit a training job from **gcloud ai-platform (ex gcloud ml-engine)** you use the [following command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/ai-platform/jobs/submit/) from the gcloud SDK:

`gcloud ai-platform jobs submit COMMAND [GCLOUD_WIDE_FLAG …]`

I want to do this programmatically, i.e. from python code (or any other language). Something like

```
import gcloud-ai-platform as gap
gap.submit_job(COMMAND)
```

Is there such a command? And if it does not exist, how can I build a workaround? (using gcloud sdk programmatically)

Comment: here there is a docs about how to build some REST API call from python, but I am not really familiar with APIs -> https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/python-client-library

Comment: here should be the desired REST API call https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/reference/rest/v1/projects.jobs/create still not sure how to call it from python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For submitting a training job, [here](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/training-jobs#formatting_your_configuration_parameters) you have an example that you can follow.

It has both methods, using gcloud and the equivalent python code.

Answer (score 3):

I found the docs a bit confusing with regards to custom images. Trick is to specify --master-image-uri via masterConfig/imageUri:

```
training_inputs = {
    'scaleTier': 'BASIC',
    'packageUris': [
    ],
    'masterConfig': {
        'imageUri': settings["AI_SERVER_URI"]
    },
    'args': [
        "java", "-cp", "MY.jar:jars/*", "io.manycore.Test",
        "jar positional argument"
    ],
    'region': 'us-central1',
    'pythonVersion': '3.7',
    'scheduling': {
        'maxRunningTime': '3600s'
    },
}

job_spec = {'jobId': jobid, 'trainingInput': training_inputs}

project_name = settings["PROJECT_ID"]
project_id = 'projects/{}'.format(project_name)

cloudml = discovery.build('ml', 'v1', credentials=self.credentials)

request = cloudml.projects().jobs().create(body=job_spec, parent=project_id)
```